# PHP version conflict in Amazon Linux EC2 instance

Tags: php, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've lunched a fresh instance from the AWS -> EC2 console panel. After that when I logged into the instance via SSH and executed the following line: (note I executed first the sudo yum update before executed the below code)

```
sudo yum install gcc make httpd php56-common php56-cli php-pear php-devel git ImageMagick-devel
```

I'm getting the following error message at the end.

```
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-process conflicts with php-process-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-xml conflicts with php-xml-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
```

From the error message I understand that lower PHP version is conflicting with new PHP version, but what I don't understand is I didn't even install the php 5.3 but some how it's there in the new instance.

Comment: I'd bet that either `php-pear` or `php-devel` have `php56` versions.

Answer (score 0):

Some instances come with more packages installed than others.  It may be that whoever created this AMI they assumed people would want PHP pre-installed on it, or that some other package that they wanted to have preinstalled on it required PHP as a dependency.